# The underlying provider failed on Open in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While accessing the database, I'm getting this error:

> The underlying provider failed

Code:

```
public string getMerchans(string searchString)
{
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM category c WHERE c.draft=0 ORDER BY c.priority ASC";
    List<merchant> merchants = dbContextIAV.merchants
                                           .Where(c => c.business_name.Contains(searchString))
                                           .OrderBy(c => c.business_name)
                                           .ToList();

    //dbContextIAV.product_merchant.FirstOrDefault().
    var response = new { status = "success", merchants = merchants };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.None,
           new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                });
}
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Check your database connection string ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is database related issue, recheck your permission and database connection string.